# Quantum Harmonic Oscillator eigenfunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, harmonic-oscillator, ground-state

I'm trying to understand why in quantum harmonic oscillator when finding ground state eigenfunction we don't use $a^\dagger$.

> For a simple harmonic oscillator the Hamiltonian is given by $$H=\hbar\omega_0\left(\hat{a}\hat{a}^\dagger-1/2\right),$$ where the operators $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{a}^\dagger$ may be expressed as $$\hat{a}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\xi+\frac{\partial}{\partial\xi}\right),$$ $$\hat{a}^\dagger=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\xi-\frac{\partial}{\partial\xi}\right),$$ where $\xi=\beta x$. You are required to find the expression for the normalized ground state eigenfunction.

This question is from my exam I just want to understand why when solution came we didn't use $a^\dagger$ its solution was given as:

[image: solution]
[image]

Comment: You'll find that eigenstates of $a^\dagger$ can't be normalized; not a bad exercise to do. People on this site g generally refer that you typeset your equations as opposed to posting pictures of them

Comment: I'm sry I'm new to this site my friend told me about it i will try to keep that in mind next time

Comment: Welcome to PhysicsSE! Note that this site supports [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). You can click the link to learn the basics. I've taken the liberty of typesetting the first part of the post for you, as an example.

Comment: To be pedantic, the professor's solution misses a phase factor in the normalization constant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have equally well used
$$
\hat{a}^\dagger= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\!\!d\xi ~ |\xi\rangle \left(\xi-\frac{\partial}{\partial\xi}\right)\langle \xi|, 
$$
instead, since the hermitian conjugate of your starting expression is
$$
\langle 0| \hat{a}^\dagger=0.
$$
You then have
$$
0=\langle 0| \hat{a}^\dagger = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\!\!d\xi ~ \langle 0|\xi\rangle \left(\xi-\frac{\partial}{\partial\xi}\right)\langle \xi| \\= 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\!\!d\xi ~   \left(\xi \psi^*_0(\xi) +\frac{\partial \psi^*_0(\xi) }{\partial\xi}\right)\langle \xi| ~~, 
$$
the last step involving integration by parts and use of the definition
$\langle 0|\xi\rangle\equiv \psi^*_0(\xi)  $.

Consequently, you get the *same* equation you had before,
$$
\xi \psi^*_0(\xi) +\frac{\partial \psi^*_0(\xi) }{\partial\xi}=0,
$$
with real solution,
$$
 \psi^*_0(\xi) \propto e^{-\xi^2/2} ~,
$$
so you may complex conjugate and suitably normalize, etc.

It should be evident that the crucial step connecting states to functions is identical.